# What does "looking into the emitter" means in small signal analysis?

Tags: bjt

In small signal analysis I had to go through the words "looking in to the emitter".

According to this looking the resistance we take differ \$r_e\$ and \$r_{\phi}\$. Can you explain what this looking into the emitter means? It's bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

It means determining the impedance the emitter presents to an external signal.

Normally you'd do it by sending a small current, much smaller than any bias so as to keep the bias conditions essentially unchanged, into the emitter, and see what the change in voltage was. Impedance is then voltage/current.

It usually involves the Re, Ie, beta, and conditions around the base terminal.